# AngularJS show image on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv4qvu3w/), I want to hover over "Your Truly" and have the image appear, while the text disappears. Does an app have to be initialized for this to work? I didn't think it did...

The angular HTML look like this (I didn't move my whole app in here, just trying to get this part to work)

```
<a ng-init="imgsrc='http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/pig-images/pig-images-12.jpg'">
<span ng-hide="imgsrc.show"
      ng-mouseover="imgsrc='http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/pig-images/pig-images-12.jpg'"
      ng-mouseout="imgsrc.hide">
      Yours Truly
</span>
<img ng-src="{{imgsrc}}"/>
</a>,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible to make something like this work without making a proper controller, though I'd discourage it. That said, I went ahead and got it working anyway:

```
<p class="text-justify last-body" ng-app>
  This growing collection of studies, curated by 
  <a ng-init="imgsrc={
    src: 'http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/pig-images/pig-images-12.jpg',
    show: false,
  };">
  <span ng-mouseover="imgsrc.show = true" ng-mouseout="imgsrc.show = false">
      Yours Truly
  </span>
  <img ng-src="{{ imgsrc.src }}" ng-show="imgsrc.show" />
  </a>, 
  is focused primarily
  on studies dealing with eh tohp ah key pig*. As a fan of mooshoo and aigeiaig, I'm open to 
  working with any dataset ranging from yakdkat studies to lakuktauka. If you would like
  to submit a study for publishing, or if you have any questions about a particular study,
  please feel free to <a href="/contact">Contact Me.</a> Thank you for visiting, and happy wamotiem!
</p>
```

This will display the image when you hover over "Yours Truly", and hide the image when you move the mouse away. The main thing preventing your example from working was the missing `ng-app` directive from the top-most element. Aside from that, I also cleaned up some of the logic to make it easier to reason out what was going on.

Here's a JSFiddle if you want to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/kv4qvu3w/2/